# DJANGO: Can I write "def view(request, x or y)"?

Tags: python, django, view, request, function

I have a view that can be accessed by two different urls. The urls carry different variables. I was wondering if there was a way I can write something like this:

```
def view(request, x or y)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: You should probably learn some basic Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your direct question: **no, you cannot write `def view(request, x or y)`**

If you have two URLs that feed into the same view, you need to create to separate dispatchers in your urls.py file. If the two URLs send different types of data, you may consider using named parameters. For example:

```
def view(request, var_from_one_url="some_default", var_from_another="some_default"):
    pass
```

From a style perspective, this probably isn't the way to go. You should probably create two separate views. If they share logic, you should break that out into another function.